# Soap BAD_REQUEST cannot parse template

Tags: php, soap, base64, soap-client

I am using a WSDL file in order to send the sms, i generated all the php class by using Wsdl2PhpGenerator\Generator. 
One of the functions  get as paramers @param base64Binary $tpl as you see the type of this parameter is base64Binary.

I've been trying to encode my $tpl without any luck

```
$tpl = __DIR__ . "/file00000"
$content = file_get_contents($tpl);
$src =  base64_encode($content);
```

The encoded result data starts with:

```
"SVMtQgAAAAFIRUFEAAAABAAAAAhGSUxFAA ...
```

This is my catch (\SoapFault $e)

```
{#355 ▼
      +"code": "BAD_REQUEST"
      +"desc": "cannot parse template"
    }
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base64 is a string not binary.

If your WSDL file wants a parameter base64Binary type, do not use `base64_encode()`, because PHP Soap does the encoding by itself.

You can pass `$content` directly as `$src`.